# FloatArray vs Array<Float>: why are they different

Tags: arrays, kotlin

Apologies if the answer is obvious, but I don't get it. I have a function that accepts a `FloatArray` so I passed a `Array<Float>` to it but it rejects it! I thought `FloatArray` was just another way of creating `Array<Float>`. What's the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some information about arrays in Kotlin is available here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/basic-types.html#primitive-type-arrays

> Kotlin also has classes that represent arrays of primitive types without boxing overhead: ByteArray, ShortArray, IntArray, and so on. These classes have no inheritance relation to the Array class, but they have the same set of methods and properties.

So `FloatArray` and `Array<Float>` are not the same, the difference is that the first has no boxing overhead.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: one is an array of primitives, the other an array of references to `Float` objects.

The difference is mostly hidden from you in Kotlin, so to explain it's probably best to go back to Java…

Java has nine basic types (if I've counted correctly). Eight of them hold a value directly: `boolean`, `byte`, `short`, `char`, `int`, `long`, `float`, and `double` — those are called ‘primitives’. The other type is a *reference*, which can point to an instance of an object or array.

Because there are cases when you need to pass one of those primitive values around as an object, Java also provides some objects which simply wrap a primitive value: `java.lang.Boolean`, `java.lang.Byte`, and so on. There's one for each primitive type.

Most code uses primitives directly, but sometimes it's handy to be able to pass an object reference. (For one thing, primitives are not nullable, so if you need to support a null, then you'll need an object reference. For another, generic code such as `List` and the other classes in the collections framework can handle only object references.)

However, object wrappers are less efficient, because each instance is a full object and takes a certain amount of memory (e.g. 16–32 bytes, depending on the Java runtime) — and that's in addition to the size of references to it (perhaps 8 bytes). The JVM caches commonly-used wrappers (e.g. true and false for booleans, and some small numbers), but for anything else you'll be creating new objects on the heap.

The wrappers are clearly distinguished from the primitive types — they're capitalised (and, in the case of `Integer`, spelled differently). In early versions of Java, they were not interchangeable; you needed to explicitly wrap (e.g. `Int(someValue)`) and unwrap (e.g. `someReference.intValue()`) when needed. Java 5 added ‘autoboxing’, where in many cases the compiler would do that for you. This blurs the distinction a bit, but most of the time you still need to be aware of it.

One of the benefits of Kotlin is that it removes some of Java's unnecessary complexity. One of the ways it does this is by hiding that distinction almost completely. The Kotlin language has no primitives: everything looks like an object. However, for reasons of efficiency, compiled Kotlin uses primitives ‘under the hood’ where possible. For example:

```
var i: Int
```

That declares an `Int` value — which will be stored as a primitive field. However:

```
var i: Int?
```

That declares a reference to an integer wrapper. (That's because primitives are not nullable, and so a primitive can't store a null value.)

This is an implementation detail: most of the time, when you're writing Kotlin, you don't need to be aware of this. But the distinction is still there at runtime, and arrays are one of the rare times it becomes visible:

- `FloatArray` is an array of primitives. It uses the minimum of memory, and interoperates with Java code that uses a `float[]` type.
- `Array<Float>` is an array of references to `Float` objects. It's more flexible, and interoperates with Java code that uses a `Float[]` type.

So you can see that these are two different types, even though they do similar things.

If you're interoperating with existing code, that will control which one you should use. If you're writing new code, then you have the choice: `FloatArray` is likely to be more efficient and use less memory — but `Array<Float>` tends to be better supported in other code (which may be able to process all the relevant types just by accepting a generic `Array`, instead of having to support `FloatArray` *and* `IntArray` *and* `LongArray` and all the others).

Answer (score 1):

Look at how [`FloatArray`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-float-array/) is declared in the documentation. It is just another class, not related to the [`Array<T>`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-array/) class at all. Sure, they represent very similar things, with the difference being that one of them would box `Float` values, and the other doesn't, as explained by the other answer. But from the perspective of the type system, they are totally unrelated. It's as if I declared:

```
class A
class B
```

and tried to pass an instance of `A` to a parameter expecting a `B`.

There are builtin methods to convert between these types though:

```
floatArrayOf(1f,2f,3f).toTypedArray() // FloatArray to Array<Float>
arrayOf(1f,2f,3f).toFloatArray() // Array<Float> to FloatArray
```

It's just that there is no implicit conversion between them, because these are unrelated types, unlike if you have subclasses and superclasses for example.